# Divide n people into m groups k times with minimal overlap

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Let's say I have

- between 60 and 100 people, who I want to split up into
- 3 to 5 groups of
- 10 to 25 people per group and I want to do that
- for 3 to 5 times

in a way where everyone meets as many people as possible with as little repetition as possible.

I've tried to do some research on my own but couldn't find anything that sounded like it was what I was looking for.

If you need any more information, just let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This needs a more formal approach. First, it's unclear if those numbers are a-priori fixed or decision-variables (and in the latter case: what about feasibility). Additionally, you need to define *repetition*. Furthermore, as *everyone meets as many people as possible* and *little repetition* are two objectives, which might be conflicting, you need to decide on how to handle this multi-objective opt (e.g. weighting importance).

Comment: Once I start the algorithm, I will have exact numbers but right now that's all I have.
How are "meeting as many different people" and "having minimal overlap over the days" different objectives? could you elaborate on that a little please?

Answer (score 3):

This is a close variant of the Social Golfer Problem. There's an algorithm due to Triska and Musliu that works well; see https://github.com/FelixHenninger/socialgolfer.js/tree/master for an implementation.

Comment: Probably gonna take me a while to work myself into the coffee code, but thanks.
I might also try looking into some pseudo code/algorithms in text form for a better understanding so I can implement it (I'm currently using python)

Answer (score 0):

You can frame this as an integer programming problem.

Define a binary variable `A[i,g,t] = 1` if person `i in N` belongs to group `g in G` at time `t in T` and `0` otherwise. Then, `M[i,j] = sum(A[i,g,t] * A[j,g,t] for g in G, t in T)` is `1` iff `i` and `j` meet.

Say you want to maximize the number of pairs of people who meet at least once. Then, your objective becomes `sum(M[i,j] for i, j in N)`.

You can express your constraints linearly:

1. Group sizes are limited: `forall g in G, forall t in T, sum(A[i,g,t] for i in N) <= quota[g,t]`.
2. Each person is assigned to exactly one group at each period: `forall i, forall t, sum(A[i,g,t] for g in G) = 1`.

There are several open source solvers that should perform well at your proposed scale.

Comment: Integer programmers tend not to work well on this formulation, because there's no symmetry breaking.